# Dump auto_increment value

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Certain tables in our MYSQL database are filled with default data (for all customers) and customer-specific data. Customer-specific records have an ID that is greater than 1000 and the default data records have IDs lower than 1000.

Every customer has his own database so if we create a new environment we dump our default database and restore it for the customer.

And that's the problem. If we dump an empty table with AUTO_INCREMENT = 1001 the auto increment value is ignored and set to 1 if the table is restored. I used mysqldump and mydumper. Both didn't work.

But if their is some data in the table the AUTO_INCREMENT is not ignored and set to it's expected value.

I've already read the mysqldump documentation but didn't found anything.
Can someone help me with this problem?

Greetings,
Arne

Comment: Note, if you need to do it programmatically then get the max + 1 and use that as the set value. Or if you need some custom value do that. But note that you cannot set the AI to something less than the current max and have it hold on the next insert (it will silently accept your request but ignore it on insert). Also, you might need to do this with a prepared statement in a stored proc or dynamic sql thru your front-end programming language.

Comment: @drew I know how to change the AUTO_INCREMENT value (so this isn't a duplicate), but I wonder why mysqldump is ignoring the AUTO_INCREMENT in the output file if its set to value 1001 and no data is provided in the table.

Comment: Because if there is no data in the table and the AI is 1001 then a delete from occurred and not a truncate that would have done a reset to 1. So it dutifully proceeds to create the table in the state the table was left at (assuming you had some reason to leave it at 1001).

Comment: Otherwise the complaint would be made "Why is it reset to 1 when I wanted the next at 1001.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. My copy of mysqldump (MySQL 5.5.46) always includes the `AUTO_INCREMENT=1001` clause with the default options. Do you get `AUTO_INCREMENT=1` or just nothing?